# Autodesk Forge: how to load the model on a node server?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to run raytracing analysis on a model from Forge. The processing is pretty heavy and it must be run on the server-side. I'm attempting to load the model into threejs (with all the geometry, materials, etc) on a node server using he svf, but I'm having trouble getting this to work. Has anybody been able to do this or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried yet, but should be best with something like [headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), where a JavaScript code running on the page can extract the information you need.